# Multiple ACPI Errors on Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, startup, bios, acpi

I have multiple errors on boot and I want to know how to fix them and not just hide them which I have seen in multiple online forums. Will these cause issues down the line? System boots to login page not to long after these appear on the screen.
I have windows 11 on one ssd and Ubuntu on a separate ssd using grub as boot-loader.
Ryzen 7950x | RTX 3070

[Screenshot of multiple errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI6Yz.jpg)